# How to prevent index.php from caching?

Tags: php, html, caching, browser-cache

I have a website (let's say `example.com`).The problem is that when I update the **index.php** page and I load `example.com`, I don't get an updated `index.php` page but the old one.

Whereas if I load `example.com/index.php`, I get the updated version of the page.

I have tried disabling the cache using the following code.

```
header('Expires: Sun, 01 Jan 2014 00:00:00 GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE);
header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

As well as:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

But nothing seems to work.

Comment: What do you mean by old index.php file?  Are you adding some content and you're getting old content ? or the `assets` of the site is not getting updated? e.g. CSS,JS ?

Comment: @Alok Yes. I am adding some content. But when I open the site, say abc.com, I get the old page (without the updated content). But if I load the site using abc.com/index.php, I get the new page (with the updated content).

Comment: Once the file is in the cache, it gets loaded from the cache and not from the server, so no matter if you change headers on server side after the file was sent once and cached by the browser. Go to your `abc.com` and hit F5 to refresh the cache in your browser. By the way, I'd say you should at least be careful when caching .php files and check for changes if you want to cache.

Comment: Try replacing this line `header("Expires: 0");`

Comment: Please use example.com instead of other sites.

Comment: use .htaccess file for it.